# Django/Python 2.7 on Google App Engine: performance fine in production, extremely slow on localhost

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am working on a new application which uses Django/Python 2.7 (ecommerce app built from within, pretty heavy-duty API).

As my title says, the app runs on GoogleAppEngine.

If I make any minor (or major) changes to CSS/HTML/JS/python and do a refresh on local host, the refresh time is painfully slow. Anywhere from 5 to 15 seconds.

Is this something with my computer? Something with the APP itself? Something with memory usage? On my boss's computer it is not as slow, but not much quicker either.

Where could I start looking for bottlenecks? Usually the case is fast on localhost, and slow in production...

Any advice on the matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really possible to answer your question without more specifics, but it does make sense for the app to run faster on Google app engine than on the built-in single-threaded runserver. I would start by downloading [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) and see what that shows you.

Comment: Ok, will checkout that Toolbar and report back here. I appreciate the response.